# Simple XNA Gui Framework for Windows

Tags: c#, user-interface, frameworks, xna

I've searched for a simple XNA Gui Framework for windows and found the "Ruminate XNA 4.0 GUI" (http://xnagui.codeplex.com/) but it doesn't have lists or tables and I don't want to write them myself.

Does anyone know a good and simple framework (best would be sth. like Valve uses in their games like counter-strike and dota) but sth. simple as the Ruminate FW is fine too.

I hope to find sth. i couldn't find in the lists that're around here yet.

Comment: Notice that XNA has been dropped by microsoft, so it **may** be hard to find a gui framework for it.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few various options for XNA GUI frameworks right now, including:

- [DigitalRune](http://www.digitalrune.com/Products/GameEngine/GameUI.aspx)
- [Squid](http://www.ionstar.org/?page_id=4%29)
- [OrbUI](http://www.thespoofnet.com/Downloads)
- [Ruminate XNA Gui](http://xnagui.codeplex.com/)
- [XNA UI System](http://xui.codeplex.com/)
- [Nuclex](http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nuclex.UserInterface&referringTitle=Home)

(Note that the first three are commercial products.)

Comment: To be honest, all of them look extra terrible.

Comment: @user1306322 Given that it's a GUI lib for dead tech, some don't look too bad...

Comment: https://neoforce.codeplex.com/ is what you might want to add, it looks good however isn't activily developed anymore, but it does it's job fine for me.

Comment: Rumors of XNA's demise are greatly exaggerated. It live on, with Microsoft's moral support, as Monogame and is more cross platform then ever.