# Textbox in a C# XNA Game

Tags: c#, textbox, xna

I'm new to XNA. I'm making a game which needs level editor. I need a textbox to get a level name and its description. So I wrote a code like this:

```
if (isSaveBox)
        {
            KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();
            Keys[] keys = ks.GetPressedKeys();
            Keys tempKey = Keys.None;

            foreach (Keys key in keys)
            {
                Keys currentKey = key;
                if (ks.IsKeyUp(lastKey))
                {
                    string toadd = key.ToString();
                    if (!(key == Keys.None) && key != Keys.Space && key != Keys.Back && key != Keys.Enter)
                    {
                        levelName += toadd;
                    }
                    else if (key == Keys.Space)
                    {
                        levelName += " ";
                    }
                    else if (key == Keys.Back)
                    {
                        levelName.Remove(levelName.Length - 1);
                        lastKey = currentKey;
                    }
                }
                if (currentKey != Keys.None && ks.IsKeyDown(currentKey))
                {
                    tempKey = currentKey;
                }
            }

            lastKey = tempKey;
            message = "Save level" + "\n" + "Enter - yes / Esc - no" + "\n" + levelName;
```

But when I try to type some letters they won't be added to the `levelName` string. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Tested the code, works fine for me. Also, I'd use elapsed time and say, every 200ms add another letter if the same key is being held, becausing typing "lol" makes it appear as "llllloooooooooooollllllllllllll"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell your code works fine. I played around with it and added some improvements. You didn't need some stuff and I made it so when you hold a key it doesn't spam so fast. I would have added support for other keys like symbols and caps, but it's quite a long switch statement for all that, so you can take a look at [this](http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2010/02/11/code-snippet-converting-keyboard-input-to-text-in-xna/) article and implement it easily.

I added a few more variable, all your textbox related stuff should now read as

```
    Keys[] lastKeys;
    KeyboardState lastKeyboardState;

    public double timer;

    public string levelName;
```

You can also add your `currentKeyboardState` variable as a global variable if you want.

Now for the code, I split it into 2 methods to prevent having to copy the code twice

```
if (isSaveBox)
{
    //Get the current keyboard state and keys that are pressed
    KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
    Keys[] keys = keyboardState.GetPressedKeys();

    foreach (Keys currentKey in keys)
    {
        if (currentKey != Keys.None)
        {
            //If we have pressed the same key twice, wait atleast 125ms before adding it again
            if (lastKeys.Contains(currentKey))
            {
                if ((gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds - timer > 125))
                    HandleKey(gameTime, currentKey);
            }
            //If we press a new key, add it
            else if (!lastKeys.Contains(currentKey))
                HandleKey(gameTime, currentKey);
        }
    }

    //Save the last keys and pressed keys array
    lastKeyboardState = keyboardState;
    lastKeys = keys;
}
```

And the method to reset the timer and actually figure out the strings (this is where you would add code for shift and symbols, etc)

```
private void HandleKey(GameTime gameTime, Keys currentKey)
{
    string keyString = currentKey.ToString();
    if (currentKey == Keys.Space)
        levelName += " ";
    else if ((currentKey == Keys.Back || currentKey == Keys.Delete) && levelName.Length > 0)
        levelName = levelName.Remove(levelName.Length - 1);
    else if (currentKey == Keys.Enter)
        return;
    else
        levelName += keyString;
    //Set the timer to the current time
    timer = gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
}
```

You could also use a `StringBuilder` for further optimization.

If you want to continue writing your own UI, go ahead. I still would recommend using a UI library (I use the newly revived [Neoforce Controls](https://neoforce.codeplex.com/)) but there is a larger discussion for that over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14778265/1218281).

Comment: I'm having two same errors at this code:
System.Array does not contain a definition for Contains and no extension method 'Contains' accepting a first argument of type System.Array could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  (at lastKeys.Contains)

Comment: You need to reference System.Linq, sorry I forgot! `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Oh lol, I forgot linq (I added every System.Collections) :P Thanks, it works now.

Comment: Okay great, No problem! I wonder what the actuall underlying problem was... It always worked from the start on mine. Also, I remember you from EE :)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use one of a XNA GUI frameworks, that contain form elements, scene managers an other useful things.

Look [here](http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/15274.aspx) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778186/simple-xna-gui-framework-for-windows)