# Create Text Box in XNA c#

Tags: c#, xna

I Want to create a text box to input the text, that like a "login box" or like a textbox in window form . Help me! Thanks for reading.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm afraid your question isn't specific enough for this site, what is the problem you are facing? What have you tried? This short article could help you improve your question so we can give the best answer possible: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. As @Jordy mentioned, when asking questions you need to be more specific. Also, please remember to search before submitting a question. You will often find that someone else has had a similar issue and it has already been resolved. For example, searching "xna textbox" came up with [XNA Textbox loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822655/xna-textbox-loop), [Textbox in a C# XNA Game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320500/textbox-in-a-c-sharp-xna-game/17323015#17323015) and many more.